# Function that toggle LED on and off

Tags: c, iar

is it possible to toggle a bit to 0 when it is 1 and to 1 when it is 0? For example,`00000000` go through the function will `00000001` and when the `00000001` go through the function again, `00000001` will become `00000000`. Is it possible?

Comment: yes. and you can do it!

Comment: Both `b = !b` and `b = 1 - b` will change 0 to 1 and 1 to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. What you want is to perform a logical XOR with `00000001` (this is called a mask):

```
MASK          INPUT     OUTPUT
00000001 XOR 00000000 = 00000001
00000001 XOR 00000001 = 00000000
```

This also makes it possible to toggle more than one bit, e.g., if your mask were `00001001`:

```
MASK          INPUT     OUTPUT
00001001 XOR 00000000 = 00001001
00001001 XOR 00001001 = 00000000
00001001 XOR 00001000 = 00000001
00001001 XOR 00000001 = 00001000
```